# What code is executed when a class is being defined?

Tags: c++, python, class, metaprogramming, introspection

When I import a module that has a class, what code is executed when that class is first read and the class object created? Is there any way I can influence what happens?

---

**Edit:** I realize my question might be a bit too general...

I'm looking for something more low-level which will allow me to do introspection from C++. I extend my C++ application with Python. I have some classes that are defined in C++ and exposed in Python. The user can inherit from these classes in the scripts and I want to be able to grab details about them when they are first defined.

Comment: What code is executed to actually create the class depends on whether it's an old-style or new-style class - do you have a preferred python version?

Comment: @Thomas Let it be Python 3, then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many possible things can happen.  The most basic:

The contents of the `class` block are executed when the it is first read.

To see this in action, this example:

```
class Foo(object):
    print "bar"

    def __init__(self):
        print "baz"
```

Will print `bar` when the module is imported.

If a class has a metaclass defined, the metaclasses `__new__` function will run after the classes block of code is run.

Example:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, kwargs):
        print "I'm the metaclass, just checking in."
        return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, kwargs)


class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = MyMeta

    print "I'm the Foo class"
```

Output:

```
I'm the Foo class
I'm the metaclass, just checking in.
```

I'm sure other bits can run as well, these are just what I am familiar with.

Comment: I think the question is about the details of a python object from a c++ point of view.... I think.  Obviously my answer doesn't address that, however that was before the question was edited to more clearly state this intent.

Answer (score 4):

Defining a class A that inherits from B and C executes:  `A = type('A', (B, C), m` where m is a dictionary containing the members of the class.

You can influence the process using metaclass programming.  There are no shortage of [blog posts](http://www.google.com/search?aq=1&oq=python%20meta&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=python%20metaprogramming) and [tutorials on the subject](http://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=python%20metaclass%20tut&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=python%20metaclass%20tutorial).

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in [metaclasses](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation), which are classes that control the creation of classes.

Answer (score 2):

The code in a class definition is executed just like any other code but any variables created (including function definitions) will be in the context of the class instead of global.  This means that you can change the class definition dynamically by adding conditional code:

```
class A(object):
    if 1==2:
        def f(self):
            print "the world has gone mad"
    else:
        def f(self):
            print "sanity rules"

>>> a = A()
>>> a.f()
sanity rules
>>>
```

However I have never seen this done, and can't think of a reason for doing it - it feels rather unpythonic.

As others have pointed out there are lots of other ways of modifying the behaviour of a class including metaclasses, inheritance and class decorators.

Answer (score 0):

Python is interpreted, so when a Python module is imported any class code at the module level is run, along with those classes' meta-classes -- this is so the classes will exist.

C++ is compiled:  the classes already exist when they are imported; there is no way to control how they are created as they are already created.